# how to convert NSArray/NSMutableArray to NSFetchedResultsController in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, core-data, xmpp, nsfetchedresultscontroller

how to convert NSArray/NSMutableArray to NSFetchedResultsController in iPhone SDK. Actually i got number of online users in NSFetchedResultsController format. But now i want to show only those users which are within 1000 meters of range. So i converted NSFetchedResultsController into NSArray , and filter array with condition, but now i want to again convert NSArray into NSFetchedResultsController type object. How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You could not convert an `NSArray` to `NSFetchedResultsController`,As of now there is no method available which support to convert `NSArray` to `NSFetchedResultsController`.

where as you could access the `NSArray` from `NSFetchedResultsController`.

See [Documentation for More info](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: so in othercase i need to create such a NSPredicate.basically i am working on xmpp client, i am getting all online user llst in a form of "XMPPUserCoreDataStorage" collections. But now i want to show only those users who are within 2000 meter range of login user. XMPPUserCoreDataStorage has a member primaryResource (of type XMPPResourceCoreDataStorage) which has a memeber latitude, longitude. how to create predicate in such a way that it shows only users within 2000 meters ??

Comment: Check the SO post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633014/search-nsfetchedresultscontroller-using-nspredicate

Comment: i have gone through that question, but that was simple. here the predicate looks bit complex.